# Showing that $(2^a - 1)\bmod (2^b - 1) = 2^{a \; \bmod \; b} - 1 $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I've been thinking on this proof for two days. I'm stuck.

> Show that, 
>   $$ (2^a - 1)\bmod (2^b - 1) = 2^{a \! \! \mod b} - 1 $$
>   where $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

I would be happy if someone can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Divide $a$ by $b$ with remainder, $a = kb + r$ with $0\leq r\lt b$. Then
dividing $x^a-1$ by $x^b-1$ gives
$$x^a-1 = (x^b-1)(x^{a-b} + x^{a-2b} + \cdots + x^{a-kb}) + (x^{a-kb} - 1).$$
Notice that $r=a\bmod b$ and that $a-kb = r$. 
Now evaluate at $x=2$, and check to make sure that everything still works out over the integers.

Comment: Sincere thanks to the downvoter for the insightful comments that help me understand what is not useful about this answer.

Answer (score 12):

If you are working modulo $2^b-1$, you have $$2^b \equiv 1 \pmod{2^b-1}.$$

Suppose that $a=nb+c$.  (That is, $a \equiv c \pmod{b}$.)  Then you can simplify 
$$2^a = 2^{nb+c} = (2^b)^n\cdot 2^c \equiv 1^n\cdot 2^c \pmod{2^b-1}.$$

The result you are looking for follows by subtracting 1 from both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Since $0\leq 2^{a\mod b} - 1 < 2^b - 1$, your question is equivalent to proving that
$$2^a - 1 \equiv 2^{a\!\!\mod  b} - 1$$
where the $\equiv$ symbol means that both sides have the same remainder when divided by $2^b-1$. This can easily be show using the properties of modulus: 
$$2^a -1 = 2^{a\mod b}2^{b\lfloor a/b\rfloor} - 1\equiv 2^{a\mod b}(2^{b\lfloor a/b\rfloor}\bmod (2^b-1))  - 1\equiv 2^{a\mod b}  - 1$$
which works because the integers $\bmod (2^b-1)$ form what is called a "ring", allowing addition and multiplication to be performed on them. The last $\equiv$ is because $2^{b}\equiv 1$ so $2^{b\lfloor a/b\rfloor}\equiv 1^{\lfloor a/b\rfloor} \equiv 1$.

Answer (score 0):

I have another approach which I think it should be easier.

We must prove that $2^a-1 \equiv 2^{a mod b}-1 \pmod{2^b-1}$

Thus, We should prove
$$2^a \equiv 2^{a mod b} \pmod{2^b-1}$$

**Proof:** Using dividing algorithm, we have:

$a = bq + r$ then $r = a - bq$

Thus we have: $2^a \equiv 2^r \pmod{2^b-1}$ then $2^a \equiv 2^{a - bq} \pmod{2^b-1}$

Now if multiply both sides of the congruence to $2^{br}$ we have:
$$2^a * 2^{bq} \equiv 2^a \pmod{2^b-1}$$

We know that $gcd(2^a, 2^b-1)=1$ (because $2^a$ is even and $2^b-1$ is odd), so we can divide both sides of the congruence by $2^a$, so we have:
$$2^{bq} \equiv 1 \pmod{2^b-1}$$

From the definition of congruence we have:
$$2^b-1 | 2^{bq}-1$$
We know that $2^{bq}-1 = (2^b-1)(2^{b(q-1)} + 2^{b(q-2)} + ... + 2^b + 1)$
Thus we have:
$$2^b-1 | (2^b-1)(2^{b(q-1)} + 2^{b(q-2)} + ... + 2^b + 1)$$
Which is trivial.

So we reached a trivial and thus all of the conclusions are reversible, then the proof is done.